# Host address issue while connecting db in php

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I faced a weird issue recently. The application was working fine but suddenly yesterday it was showing this error which is attached, It says the password issue, but the password is correct. To run the application again, I've tried replacing the '127.0.0.1' to the inet address in the db connect file and the application is now working fine. Do someone know why '127.0.0.1' is not working. As currently, it is having inet address, I'm worried there will be a new issue in the future.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Mysql can only be bind to 1 network interface. Probably something changed in the mysql configuration (or it was upgraded or similar) and mysql started listening to the IP address instead of the local ip/socket?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Have you tried restarting the mysql server? Have you made any changes (software updates etc) on the server? You also seem to be running an old application on an old and unsupported version of PHP (since it's using the now removed `mysql_*`-api). Might be time to upgrade so you at least get security updates.

Comment: The part of the error saying _"Could not connect TABLE"_ looks unusual ! Have you done something odd with one of the tables? Or maybe deleted one??

Answer (score 1):

Without more info it's hard to say exactly. But first things first, You should move away from mysql_connect. Here is a quote from PHP.net

> Warning
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
> 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide. Alternatives to this function
> include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_connect()
> PDO::__construct()
> ```

Other then that off the top of my head I'd say it looks like the user root is configured to only have access from a specific domain. As in root@myhostname not root@localhost.

Easiest way to check would be:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

And make sure root@localhost or root@% has access. If not

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM root@whatever;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourDatabaseName . * TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

You can set it up for root@% but it's a bad idea from a security standpoint.